# Can the directional derivative be defined as $\lim_{\|v\|\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{v})-f(\mathbf{x})}{||\mathbf{v}||}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I am thinking about the directional derivative. I think that the easiest way how to express it is

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f(\mathbf{x})}{\partial \mathbf{v}} = \lim_{||v|| \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{v})-f(\mathbf{x})}{||\mathbf{v}||},
\end{equation}

but the directional derivative is usually defined as

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f(\mathbf{x})}{\partial  \mathbf{v}} = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(\mathbf{x} + h \mathbf{v})-f(\mathbf{x})}{h}.
\end{equation}

Can you rigorously explain the transition from first and second definition?

Thanks!

---

**Edit:**

Just to make it clear.

The first definition is primarily wrong because the orientation of the directional vector is not fixed. So if I correct it like this (switching to conventional notation)

\begin{equation}
\nabla_{\mathbf{v}} f(\mathbf{x}) = \lim_{||\mathbf{v}|| \to 0} \frac{f(\mathbf{x} + ||\mathbf{v}||\mathbf{\hat{v}})-f(\mathbf{x})}{||\mathbf{v}||},
\end{equation}

it makes a little bit more sense ($ \mathbf{\hat{v}}$ denotes unit vector). BUT the norm allows to get close to zero just from right side ($ ||\mathbf{v}|| \to 0+ $) and the limit makes sense even for vector reversal (~ negative norm). So we can actually use any scalar $h$ scaling the vector and write the derivative as

\begin{equation}
\nabla_{\mathbf{v}} f(\mathbf{x}) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(\mathbf{x} + h\mathbf{\hat{v}})-f(\mathbf{x})}{h}
\end{equation}

or you can find it equivalently written as

\begin{equation}
\nabla_{\mathbf{v}} f(\mathbf{x}) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(\mathbf{x} + h\mathbf{v})-f(\mathbf{x})}{h||\mathbf{v}||}.
\end{equation}

Comment: If it is a "directional" derivative, in what direction is the derivative. If you wanted the derivative in the "direction" of $(1,1,2)$, how would your definition do that? Your definition doesn't restrict $v$ to be "in that direction."

Comment: As an aside, if you want to allow non-unit $\mathbf{v}$, you get a better operator if you *don't* normalize: for example, you *want* to have $$\nabla_{2 \mathbf{v}} f = 2 \nabla_{\mathbf{v}} f$$
An example of the benefit is that this version still satisfies the formula
$$ \nabla_{\mathbf{v}} f = \mathbf{v} \cdot \nabla f$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition is not "directional," since $v$ in your definition can be in *any* direction. Note, if you were just in $1$ dimension, the limit $$\lim_{\delta\to 0} \frac{f(x+\delta)-f(x)}{|\delta|}$$ isn't even defined when $f$ is normally differentiable, because when $\delta\to 0-$ the limit is $-f'(x)$and when $\delta\to 0+$ the limit is $f'(x)$.

Essentially, the "directional derivative" can be seen as taking $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf v$ and defining a new function on the real numbers: $g(h) = f(\mathbf x + h\mathbf v)$. This $g$ computes the value of $f$ on the line through $\mathbf x$ in the direction of $\mathbf v$, and the directional derivative of $f$ at $\mathbf x$ in the direction $\mathbf v$ is defined as $g'(0)$.

Comment: It's worse than that; his definition doesn't even make sense from a notational viewpoint!

Comment: thanks, now I understand ... :-)

Comment: Please, look at the edit above. I want to know if I get it right. (Sorry for asking to obvious/stupid question.)

Comment: That still doesn't deal with the case of $h<0$. You are allowing, which is not the same as my definition.  For example, in your definition, $f(\mathbf v)=|\mathbf v|$ has direction derivative at $\mathbf v=0$, but in my definition, it does not. That's because you have $|v|\to 0$. Also, your definition is confusing since nothing make $\mathbf v$ be in the same vector as $\hat{\mathbf{v}}$ - you are essentially using $\hat{\mathbf{v}}$ in your limit as a stand-in for a positive real - you might as well say $$\lim_{h\to 0+}$$

Answer (score 4):

Your first definition makes no sense really, since you're using $\Delta \mathbf{x}$ simultaneously as a parameter and variable (which you're taking a limit over). The second (correct) definition thus uses a separate variable over which the limit is taken, used to scale the positional vector.

Comment: sorry, corrected

Comment: It still doesn't make sense I'm afraid; the RHS is what doesn't work, as explained above. As for the LHS, you're using unconventional notation (the nabla symbol is almost always used), but I get what you mean.